# RHEL on HP DL380 Gen9 boots to blank screen

Tags: hp-proliant, rhel7

I have an HP DL380 Gen9 server that I just installed RHEL 7.0 on. Yesterday I was able to log in and setup a few tools and users. Overnight I turned the server off. This morning when I boot the server gets through initialization and gets to what appears to be a RHEL init screen and then the screen goes black.

All of the hardware indicators show green through ILO and it boots normally.

The screen shows black on both the connected monitor and the remote console.

Am I doomed to just re-installing the OS? Anything else that could be causing the OS init to abort?

Comment: Remove the words `rhgb` and `quiet` from the boot command line, and try again. This should give you some additional information.

Comment: Have you tried connecting using the ILO? Also, shouldn't you be using RHEL 7.2? Are you using current media?

Comment: I can connect with ILO but the outcome is the same. Shows a blank screen. HP doesn't support RHEL 7.2 on the Gen9 servers. They recommend 6.5 or 7.0. Media is brand new download from the redhat site.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Your rhgb and quite provided some more issue but it took awhile to capture the error. Getting Failed to start LSB: Starts the Spacewalk Daemon.See 'systemctl status rhnsd.service' for details. Which appears to be this:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1188963

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The note from Michael Hampton exposed the core issue which is this:
https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2015-2380.html#Red

Booting to single user command line mode and running yum update resolved the issue.

Comment: Wow! That's messed up.